# Python - How to do accumulative sums depending on the value of a column

Tags: python, cumsum

I have a dataframe and I want to add a column that should be the accumulative sum of one of the columns but only if the value of another column is a specific one.

For example, my dataframe is as follows:

```
| Type | Quantity |

| A | 30 |

| B | 10 |

| B | 5 |

| A | 3 |
```

I would like to add a column `SumA` that would only do the accumulative sum of the quantities when `Type == A`.

I have tried this:

```
data['SumA'] = data['Quantity'].cumsum() if data[(data['Type'] == 'A')]
```

I keep getting errors and I'm not sure how I can solve them, could someone please give me a hand?

I would like to get something like this:

```
| Type | Quantity | Sum A | Sum B |

| A | 30 | 30 | 0 |

| B | 10 | 30 | 10 |

| B | 5 | 30 | 15 |

| A | 3 | 33 | 15 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about somewhat general solution which can surely be optimized (I will try and continue and work on it):

So we iterate over the unique values of our `Type` column to create `sum{value}` column, then each column will consist the `cumsum` of their respected `Type` value while non matching values will be `NaN`.

Then I fill the `NaN` values with the nearest valid value and the last row is to satisfy the special case where the first item in the row is `NaN` and needs to be `0`

```
for column in data['Type'].unique():
  column_name = f'sum{column}'
  data[column_name] = data[data['Type'] == column]['Quantity'].cumsum()
  data[column_name].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
  data[column_name].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

output:

```
    Type    Quantity    sumA   sumB
0   A       30          30.0   0.0
1   B       10          30.0   10.0
2   B       5           30.0   15.0
3   A       3           33.0   15.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting here is a syntax error. Pandas does not support selection for rows with the if command.

Instead to select the rows you want you can do this:

```
data[(data['Type'] == 'A')]['Quantity']
```

This will show the quantity column of the rows that have Type equal to 'A'

So in your case in order for this code to work this will become:

```
data['sumA'] = data[(data['Type'] == 'A')]['Quantity'].cumsum()
```

In order to get the expected output you just need to do this twice for columns A and B and fill any missing nan value.

```
data['sumA'] = data[(data['Type'] == 'A')]['Quantity'].cumsum() 
data['sumB'] = data[(data['Type'] == 'B')]['Quantity'].cumsum() 

# Fill nan values with the previously available value
data.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# The first values don't have any previous value, so fill with zero
data.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

This returns the expected value

Comment: Please follow the excepted output the OP provided.